# creating multiple sprite nodes with slight variations?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode

I have a game menu that displays multiple achievements which are defined as SKSpriteNodes there are 18 of them and they only have slight variations in the positioning, here is a snippet of the code:

```
    Achievement1 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    Achievement1.position = CGPointMake(-120, 100)
    page1ScrollView.addChild(Achievement1)

    Achievement2 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    Achievement2.position = CGPointMake(0, 100)
    page1ScrollView.addChild(Achievement2)

    Achievement3 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    Achievement3.position = CGPointMake(120, 100)
    page1ScrollView.addChild(Achievement3)

    Achievement4 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    Achievement4.position = CGPointMake(-120, -25)
    page1ScrollView.addChild(Achievement4)
```

Also I have gone to great lengths to define all of them one by one as vars as seen here:

```
  var Achievement1: SKSpriteNode!
  var Achievement2 = SKSpriteNode()
  var Achievement3 = SKSpriteNode()
  var Achievement4 = SKSpriteNode()
  var Achievement5 = SKSpriteNode()
  var Achievement6 = SKSpriteNode()
  var Achievement7 = SKSpriteNode()
  var Achievement8 = SKSpriteNode()
```

It looks like a complete mess and just takes up too much space. I want to be able to define all of the sprite nodes and have them all able to be pressed to display a box that states what the achievement is for like so:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    let location: CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let node: SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


    if (node == Achievement1) {

        //achievement details here

   }
```

I am still new to this swift language and I am not very advanced yet I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think your code is a mess, try to find *patterns* in your code.

See those `Achievement1`, `Achievement2`, `Achievement3`, `Achievement4` thingys? When you see this kind of pattern, you should probably create an array to store the achievements.

I'm sure you know how to use an array, so I won't talk about it too much. For more info, you can go to the definition of the `Array` class.

The other pattern you might notice is that you use the same arguments to create the sprite nodes. The only difference between the achievements is their positions.

The best way to fix this is to create a method:

```
func createAchievement(location: CGPoint) -> SKSpriteNode {
    let node = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    node.position = location
    return node
}
```

And you just need one line to add a new achievement to the aforementioned array:

```
someArray.append(createAchievement(CGPointMake(-120, 100)))
```

EDIT:

If you use the `indexOf(_:)` (or `index(of:)` in swift 3), you can create a switch statement instead of an if statement:

```
switch someArray.indexOf(node) {
    case 0:
        // this means that the first achievement is tapped!
    case 1:
        // this means that the second achievement is tapped!
    case 2:
        // this means that the third achievement is tapped!
}
```

Comment: does this still allow me to use the nodes generated in my touchesbegan method?

Comment: @Astrum Yes of course! To check whether `node` is the first achievement, use `node == someArray[0]`! To check against the second achievement, use `node == someArray[1]`. You can figure out the rest!

Comment: @Astrum You can also use the `index(of:)` method mentioned by Grimxn in his answer. But if you're using Swift 2.x, use `indexOf(_:)` instead.

Comment: why do i have to use that indexof(_:) in my touchesbegan method? does that allow me not to have to write them all out individually in the touches began method?

Comment: If you use `indexOf`, you can create a switch statement that switches the index of the touched node (more elegant IMO) instead of an if statement (less elegant) @Astrum

Comment: could you give me a light example in your answer of it?

Comment: @Astrum Edited please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: just neglect that above bit I ended up using  var Achievements = [SKSpriteNode]() also  how do i go about adding it to the page? i mean i tried page1ScrollView.addChild(Character[0]) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

About layout when you have a big number of items to show, you can think to use a table or a page control. Because I'm lazy I don't like to scroll a table only to see all the game achievements so usually I prefeer to use PageControl. 
You can build in `UIKit` your `UIPageControl` and integrate it to your game menus.
If you don't know how to integrate `UIPageControl` you can use this sprite-kit project **[GBPageControl](https://github.com/jhurt/GBPageControl)**

```
import GBPageControl

var pageControl:PageControl!
//Add the page control to the scene. Add any content that will be paged directly to the pageControl:
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    pageControl = PageControl(scene: self)
    addContent()
    pageControl.enable(4)
}

private func addContent() {
    for var i = 0; i < 4; i++ {
        let node = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
        node.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        let x = self.size.width / 2.0 + self.size.width * CGFloat(i)
        let y = self.size.height / 2.0
        node.position = CGPoint(x:x, y:y)
        pageControl.addChild(node)
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        if pageControl.handleTouch(touch) {
            //no op
        }
        else {
            //handle touch
        }
    }
}
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
    pageControl.willMoveFromView(view)
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Update**:

About your Achievements code you could try to do:

```
enum MedalType: Int {
    case Gold = 1
    case Silver = 2
    case Bronze = 3
}
class Achievement:SKSpriteNode {
    init(color:SKColor,size:CGSize,name:String,medalType:MedalType) {
        super.init(texture: nil,color:color,size:size)
        self.name = name
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var achievements:[Achievement]!
    var aNames: [String]!
    var totalAchievements: Int = 45

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    var counter : Int = 0
    let deltaX:CGFloat = 120
    let deltaY:CGFloat = 10
    for i in 0..<totalAchievements {
        var aColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        var aSize = CGSizeMake(100,100)
        var medal = MedalType.Bronze

        switch i {
        case 10:
            aColor = SKColor.redColor()
            aSize = CGSizeMake(100,150)
            medal = MedalType.Silver
        case 25:
            aColor = SKColor.blueColor()
            aSize = CGSizeMake(100,200)
            medal = MedalType.Gold
        default:
            break
        }
        let name = "achievement\(i)"
        let a = Achievement.init(color: aColor, size: aSize, name: name, medalType: medal)
        aNames.append(name)

        //handle your position has you wish with counter, deltaX e deltaY
        //...
        a.position = CGPointMake(deltaX, deltaY)
        addChild(a)
       }
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
        let location: CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node: SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if (aNames.contains(node.name!)) {

            print("You have touch achievement \(node.name)")
            let currentAchievement = achievements[aNames.indexOf(node.name!)!]
            // Use your currentAchievement touched
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array...

```
let achievements = [SKSpriteNode](repeating: SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.white(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)), count: 8) // Swift 3 colour name
let positions = [CGPoint(x: -120, y: 100), CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100) /* ... */]
for i in 0 ..< min(achievements.count, positions.count) { // For safety - obviously these should be the same
    achievements[i].position = positions[i]
}

// Then in your touch routine...
if let index = achievements.index(of: self.nodeAtPoint(location)) {
    // do something with achievements[index]
}
```

... and don't capitalise variables - the Swift convention is that only types are capitalised...